# Logging full tracebacks in Google App Engine for a flask app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

For some reason, whenever my Flask application raises an exception, I only see the first line of the stack trace in the App Engine logs. What is the right way to log full tracebacks in Google App Engine for a flask app? I trued this, which is obviously a hack, though it does do the job of getting the traceback into the GAE logs through writing them to stderr:

```
class TraceHandler(Handler):
    """We capture unhandled exceptions within applicatoin requests,
    and write the trace to stdout. This puts the trace in the 
    GAE application logs."""

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize the handler.
        """
        Handler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        import sys
        import traceback
        ei = sys.exc_info()
        try:
            exception = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(ei[0], ei[1], ei[2], None))
            es = exception.strip()
            if es and es != 'None':
                sys.stderr.write(exception)
        except IOError:
            pass    # see issue 5971
        finally:
            del ei


th = TraceHandler()
app.logger.addHandler(th)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-line tracebacks actually do appear in the GAE logs. To see beyond the first line you have to press the little plus icon.